# Displaying reponse received from RESTful web service using Backbone.js on next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I am new to Backbone.js and Handlebar.js. I am calling an Java RESTful web service in my code and after that I am receiving an response object which contains a json response.

Now what I want is to render the response object and using the handlebar templates I have to show the result on the next page.

As I am new to this technologies I am not able to understand in which direction I should go. What to search for, or what will be the correct strategy?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to render a view after Ajax call. I am not sure what you want. If you are looking for pagination [here is the link which can help you](http://addyosmani.com/blog/backbone-paginator-new-pagination-components-for-backbone-js/).

If you meant to load a view after a ajax call, here is the simple solution.

```
App.PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: Handlebars.compile('some {{value}}'),

    render: function(){
        var newObject = this.model.toJSON();
        $.ajax({
            url:"/user",
            context:this, //pass view context
            success:function(data){
                var modelObject = JSON.parse(data);
                this.$el.html(that.template(modelObject));
            }
        });
    }

});
```